# no viable conversion from 'string *' (aka 'basic_string<char> *') to 'shared_ptr<string>

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

So I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    {
        shared_ptr<string> str = new string("Marius");
        cout << str + " MMG";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

By compiling it with:

```
clang++ -Wall -g -std=c++14 test.c++ -o test
```

I get:

```
test.c++:11:22: error: no viable conversion from 'string *' (aka 'basic_string<char> *') to 'shared_ptr<string>'
                shared_ptr<string> str = new string("Marius");
```

Where is the mistake?
With GCC I get the same error.

Comment: the mistake is that… there's no conversion from `string *` to `shared_ptr<string>`. Just what the compiler says.

Comment: You can't initialize the `shared_ptr` using `=` because that requires an implicit conversion. Call the constructor explicitly. Or use `make_shared` for great justice.

Comment: @Marius MG using its constructor.

Comment: Also `cout << str + " MMG";` is not going to do what you expect, it should be `*str`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor for `std::shared_ptr` that takes a raw pointer is `explicit`.

Also note there is no `operator=` that takes a raw pointer, so the following would *also* fail to compile:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr;
ptr = new std::string{"Marius"};
```

To construct one properly, there are two options:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr{new std::string{"Marius"}};

// or the (much) preferred
auto ptr = std::make_shared<std::string>("Marius");
```

Comment: _"there is no `operator=` that takes a raw pointer."_ That's irrelevant, there is no assignment involved here.

Comment: Agreed, I wanted to be clear that `std::shared_ptr<T> p; p = new T()` would also be a problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe split it into two sentences and say that more clearly, to avoid the misunderstanding I made.